# How concatenate a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have a LinkedList:

```
Linkedlist<String> m = new Linkedlist<String>();
```

and it contains:

```
m = {"apple", "banana", "pineapple", "orange", "mango"};
```

My current code is:

```
string s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
{
  s += a.get(i);
  s += a.get(i);
  s += a.get(i);
  return s;
}
```

What I expect:

`[apple]` or `[banana, orange]` or `[apple, pineapple, mango]`.

But my result is always:

`[apple, apple, apple]`

What must I do to get the expected output?

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: Thanks, pbd , this is my first time to ask question. I just want to know how to use loop to loop over the linked list and use compound additive operator to show the result I wanted.

Comment: @Pbd OP *probably* meant LinkedList, and this is *probably* Java, but you should probably ask first before editing the question like that without being sure. Editing a post to change class names is something one should almost never do.

Comment: @Dukeling, sorry about my mistake. It is a java question.

Comment: @Dukeling fine, will keep in mind next time onwards. thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about the built-in LinkedList class (not Linkedlist, Java is case sensitive), it has a `toString` method which return the list in `[]` instead of `{}`. Or do you need to use a loop or are you using a custom class?

Comment: @Dukeling right now I just used foreach loop to do it. but I always got  same result, e.g [apple, apple, apple].  I never got result such as [apple], or [apple, orange], or [banana, orange, mango]

Comment: If you get `[apple, apple, apple]` with a foreach loop, my guess is that the linked-list contains only `apple` 3 times, or you just took the first element each time. You might want to construct and post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem you're having.

Comment: @Dukeling my code is: My code is:

string s = "";
for(int i = 0; i< m.size(); i++)
{
s += a.get(i);   
s += a.get(i);
s += a.get(i);
return s;

}

Comment: Everything in the `{}` will get run for each value of `i`, so you'll do `s+=a.get(0)` 3 times and then return. Just have 1 `s += a.get(i)` and put the `return` *after* the `}`.

Comment: @Dukeling thanks for your reply, but my teacher said we should use the way likes this: s+= part1; s+= part2, s+= part3. He said use this way to help customer to have different choices. He want our code can help customer to choose more than two fruits but less than three from the list.

Comment: The way to do it with a for loop would be the way I recommended above. If your teacher wants something else, the best idea is probably to ask them about it, because we'd just be speculating.

Answer (score 1):

You can output `List` in different ways.

**1)** First is closest to your code

```
LinkedList<String> m = new LinkedList<String>();
m.add("apple");
m.add("banana");
m.add("pineapple");
m.add("orange");
m.add("mango");

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(String value : m)
    s.append(value);

System.out.println(s);
```

Output is (perhaps you would like to format it a bit)

```
applebananapineappleorangemango
```

**2)** Easiest way, in my opinion, is to connect [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from apache.

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(m, ", "));
```

Output

```
apple, banana, pineapple, orange, mango
```

**3)** If you need it just for debug, you can simple use `toString()` from list. So

```
System.out.println(m.toString());
```

gives you

```
[apple, banana, pineapple, orange, mango]
```